# How do I make Horizontal Recyclerview scroll infinitely without scrolling back to the first item

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling

I have a Recyclerview that autos-crolls when the activity is started. The items in the recyclerview are 4 but when the scroll reaches the last(4th) item, it has to scroll back to the first item to start over again. What I want is the scroll to just continue to the first item when the last item is reached. My code is as shown below:

```
private void setAdsRecyclerView() {
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false) {

        @Override
        public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
            LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(getContext()) {

                private static final float SPEED = 300f;// Change this value (default=25f)

                @Override
                protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                    return SPEED / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
                }

            };
            smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
            startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
        }

    };

    adsRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adsRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adsRecyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    adsParseAdapter = new AdsParseAdapter(adsParseItems, getContext());
    adsRecyclerview.setAdapter(adsParseAdapter);

    LinearSnapHelper linearSnapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
    linearSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(adsRecyclerview);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() < adsParseAdapter.getItemCount() - 1) {
                layoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(adsRecyclerview, new RecyclerView.State(), layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() + 1);
            } else {
                layoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(adsRecyclerview, new RecyclerView.State(), 0);
            }

        }
    }, 5000, 4000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Viewpager instead of recycler view in your app.

```
swipeTimer = Timer()
        swipeTimer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                runOnUiThread {
                    if (num == NUM_PAGES) {
                        num = 0
                    }
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(num++, true)
                }
            }
        }, 500, 3000)
```

This code will also automatically swipes your all images by your required time and also comes back to the first one after the last one.

Adapter code will be like below :

```
    class TempAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    ArrayList<Integer> imagesList = new ArrayList<>();
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    public TempAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imagesList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imagesList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
        return view == o;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout,container,false);
        ImageView imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        imageView.setImageResource(imagesList.get(position));
        container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

And set adater to viewpager from activity like :

```
vpImageAdapter = VPImageAdapter(this, imageList)
viewPager.adapter = vpImageAdapter
```

Comment: Then use the adapter how in the ViewPager??

Comment: @crixus i have updated the code

Comment: I am using Java not Kotlin please

Comment: @crixus i have updated the code

Comment: I got this error: "The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 0, found: 4 Pager"

Comment: I have solved the problem now can you please tell me what you mean by or show me the full code of : if (num == NUM_PAGES) {
                        num = 0
                    }

Comment: num will be your incremental int and NUM_pages will be your total number of images in the list.